# What is correct approach for test of divergence/convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^3+n+1}}{n^4}$

Tags: calculus

What is the correct approach for determining if the following series is convergent or divergent?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^3+n+1}}{n^4}$$

My thought process was to use the limit comparison test where:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^3+n+1}}{n^4} \leq \frac{1}{n^4}$$

According the p-series test this series converges. Is this correct?

Comment: No, it's not correct. Is it true that $\sqrt{n^3 + n + 1} \le 1$?

Comment: I love how we get not one but two instant answers that make no attempt to address the asker's thought process, but just pull an answer out of thin air.

Comment: @ T.Bongers, yes silly mistake on my part. seems all this studying for finals has turned my brain into jello :D. What approach would you suggest?

Comment: Comparison or limit comparison *does* work, you just need to be a lot more careful. Note that $\sqrt{n^3 + n + 1} \approx. n^{3/2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some experience with such problems, the answer is obvious: the terms approximate $n^{-5/2}$, so the series converges. But how do we approach the problem from first principles?

The first step is to make a crude estimate of the magnitudes involved. In this case, we have numerator $\sqrt{n^3+n+1}\approx n^{3/2}$, and denominator $n^4$. This gives a crude estimate of $\dfrac{n^{3/2}}{n^4}=n^{-5/2}$.

As I expect you know, $\sum n^\alpha$ converges if $\alpha<-1$, so this crude estimate converges.

The next step is to show that your crude estimate of the numerator is a good enough approximation. That means that it is less than the true value by a constant factor $C$, i.e. $\sqrt{n^3+n+1}<Cn^{3/2}$ for some $C$. Then you have $\sum \dfrac{\sqrt{n^3+n+1}}{n^4}<C\sum n^{-5/2}$, which converges. So look for $C$ such that $n^3+n+1<C^2n^3$ for all $n$, and you are done. In fact you only need to find $C$ such that this inequality holds for all *sufficiently large* $n$, which often makes the problem much simpler.

In the previous paragraph, I implicitly used the fact that all the terms are positive. If this is not the case, you might have a little more work to do.

Answer (score 1):

the inequality is false, just use limit comparison with the convergent

$$ \sum \frac{1}{n^{5/2}} $$

Comment: This doesn't quite work, because the general term of the series is larger than $\frac{1}{n^{5/2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{n^3+n+1} \leq \sqrt{2n^3}$, so:

$$\frac{\sqrt{n^3+n+1}}{n^4} \leq \frac{\sqrt{2n^3}}{n^4}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n^{5/2}}.$$

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{2}}{n^{5/2}}$ converges, by the comparison test our series converges as well.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a series with positive terms, you may use *equivalents*: a polynomial function is asymptotically equivalent to its leading term, so
$$\frac{\sqrt{n^3+n+1}}{n^4}\sim_\infty\frac{\sqrt{n^3}}{n^4}=\frac 1{n^{5/2}},$$
which is a $p$-series ($p=5/2$)  converging to $\zeta(5/2)$.

Answer (score -3):

Hint: use the ratio test with ${1\over {n^{5\over 2}}}$

${{\sqrt{n^3+n+1}\over n^4}}$

$={{n^{3\over 2}\over n^4}}
{{\sqrt{1+{1\over n^2}+{1\over n^3}}}}$

$={1\over {n^{5\over 2}}}{{\sqrt{1+{1\over n^2}+{1\over n^3}}}}$

Comment: Ratio test fails for all power series $\sum n^{p}$.